# subquery returned more than 1 value. How do I fix this

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, subquery

I'm trying to get the output
  `<xp><p id="aa"><v>hi</v></p><p id="bb"><v>care</v></p></xp>`

out of the below query.But end up getting an error subquery returns more than 1.
ANy help would be greatly apreciated

Below is my SQL query

```
declare @tmp1 table(ProductId nvarchar(256),Extended nvarchar(max))
insert into @tmp1 values(1,'

<xp><p id="181"><v>@1@</v></p><p id="184"> 
    <v>@2@</v></p></xp>')

declare @tmp2 table(ID int,Descr nvarchar(max))
insert into @tmp2 values(181,'aa')
insert into @tmp2 values(184,'bb')


declare @tmp5 table(ID int,Name nvarchar(max),propID int)
insert into @tmp5 values(1,'hi',181)
insert into @tmp5 values(2,'how',181)
insert into @tmp5 values(3,'are',181)
insert into @tmp5 values(1,'take',184)
insert into @tmp5 values(2,'care',184)
insert into @tmp5 values(3,'bye',184)


declare @tmp3 table(ProductId nvarchar(256),Extended nvarchar(max),rownum int)
insert into @tmp3
select ProductId,
Isnull((Select  t5.name from @tmp5 t5 inner join @tmp2 t2 on t5.id + ',' + 
t5.propID =item + ',' + t2.id and t5.propID=t2.id and  
convert(nvarchar(max),t5.id)= item),item)Extended
,DENSE_RANK()Over( order by productid ) 
 from @tmp1 t1
CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitString([Extended] ,'@')  
select * from @tmp3
```

Comment: This is invalid SQL `Select  t5.name from @tmp5 t5 inner join @tmp2 t2 on t5.id + ',' + t5.propID =item + ',' + t2.id and t5.propID=t2.id and  convert(nvarchar(max),t5.id)= item`. I am not even sure what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: Additionally, HTML building inside SQL server is dodgy. SQL Server is simply not designed for this. What is your overall goal?

Comment: Basically need to generate a report from database. And I need the output based on above 3tables to be

Comment: There is too little information for me to work with. You probably should use [`FOX XML`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/for-xml-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) construct to generate HTML. There are plenty tutorials and other info on how to do it.

Comment: Also, you have not answered my first comment regarding invalid SQL.

Comment: Well basically I was trying to figure out unique values among the third table.. But couldn't find any. Hence concatenated ..but got subquery error.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "I was trying to figure out unique values among the third table.. But couldn't find any.". I suggest you start with a small simple query to gradually build it up to where you want it to be. Look into FOX XML as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are some things you really should avoid:

- store XML as `NVARCHAR()`
- think of HTML as the same as XML (unless it is strict XHTML)
- deal with XML with string methods

As long as this is valid XML (or XHTML) you can try this:

Your sample

```
declare @tmp1 table(ProductId nvarchar(256),Extended nvarchar(max))
declare @tmp1 table(ProductId nvarchar(256),Extended nvarchar(max))
insert into @tmp1 values('P1','<xp><p id="181"><v>1</v></p><p id="184"><v>2</v></p></xp>') 
                       ,('P2','<xp><p id="184"><v>3</v></p><p id="184"><v>1</v></p></xp>') 

declare @tmp2 table(ID int,Descr nvarchar(max))
insert into @tmp2 values(181,'aa')
insert into @tmp2 values(184,'bb')


declare @tmp5 table(ID int,Name nvarchar(max),propID int)
insert into @tmp5 values(1,'hi',181)
insert into @tmp5 values(2,'how',181)
insert into @tmp5 values(3,'are',181)
insert into @tmp5 values(1,'take',184)
insert into @tmp5 values(2,'care',184)
insert into @tmp5 values(3,'bye',184)
```

--the query

```
SELECT ProductId
      ,(
        SELECT t2.Descr     AS [@id]
              ,t5.[Name]    AS [v]
        FROM A.Casted.nodes('/xp/p') B(p)
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT B.p.value('@id','int') AS p_id
                           ,REPLACE(B.p.value('(v/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)'),'@','') AS p_Val) C
        INNER JOIN @tmp2 t2 ON C.p_id=t2.ID
        INNER JOIN @tmp5 t5 ON t5.propID=t2.ID AND t5.ID=C.p_Val
        FOR XML PATH('p'),ROOT('xp'),TYPE
      ) AS YourXmlDetails
FROM @tmp1 t1
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST(t1.Extended AS XML) Casted) A;
```

the result (e.g. one line)

```
<xp>
  <p id="aa">
    <v>hi</v>
  </p>
  <p id="bb">
    <v>care</v>
  </p>
</xp>
```

The idea in short:

- We use APPLY to get your XML in a typed column (better was a typed column in the source table)
- We use APPLY to read the `<p>` elements and one more APPLY to retrieve the values.
- We join the other tables
- We build a new XML using `FOR XML`

Hint: You are using a string splitting function to deal with the `@`. This might point to multiple values like `@1@2@`, but your given sample does not show so. If you'd need this, you can try to split the returned `p_Val` and join to this list.

Comment: This query works good. But when I INSERT multiple rows into @tmp1 , it gives all result in the same XML.

Comment: For example if I enter 
insert into @tmp1 values('P1','<xp><p id="181"><v>1</v></p><p id="184"><v>2</v></p></xp>')
insert into tmp1 values('P2','<xp><p id="184"><v>3</v></p><p id="184"><v>1</v></p></xp>') 
then your query is giving me result as [ <xp><p id="aa"><v>hi</v></p><p id="bb"><v>take</v></p><p id="bb"><v>care</v></p><p id="bb"><v>bye</v></p></xp>]
Where as I'm looking for the output to be in tableform as below
ProductID Extended
P1  <xp><p id="aa"><v>hi</v></p><p id="bb"><v>take</v></p></xp>
P2  <xp><p id="bb"><v>care</v></p><p id="bb"><v>bye</v></p></xp>

Comment: @ish_dev, valid point... See my updated answer. The trick is, to let the XML be created as a correlated sub-query with the `TYPE` hint.

Comment: @ish_dev, always happy to help... If this solved your issue, it would be kind to close the question by checking the acceptance check. This will mark this thread as *answered* and will pay some points to your and to my account.